# how to include a text file(secondary file) which is used for storing Jar's file data in the windows task scheduler?

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks, executable-jar

I tried to make a day counter program in which it starts to counts the days from specific date and it will update itself everyday.I used a text file to save the starting date.For the updating part, i tried to use the task scheduler so that my program is being run every single day at a specific time and it will be updated every time it is beginning to run.

I added the jar file as a task in task scheduler.But, the problem is that it does not use the txt file that is inside the folder which also contains the jar file.
I get the file not found exception.

What can i do now?is it possible to somehow include the txt file in time scheduler as well.Is there any other way that i run this program every day without using time scheduler?

Comment: Can you please show the structure of the jar file? You can store the file on the local disk and pass it absolute path to the program that uses it.

Comment: are you talking about the code of the jar file?